# Javascript include leads to 500 Error

Tags: javascript

So I'm using the following code on an html page:

```
var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
    upclick(
     {
      element: uploader,
      action: 'helpers/uploadScript.php', 
      onstart:
        function(filename)
        {
          alert('Start upload: '+filename);
        },
      oncomplete:
        function(response_data) 
        {
          alert(response_data);
        }
     });
```

That should call a Google file uploader I found, but instead I'm receiving the following errors:

```
GET http://***/helpers/upclick.js 500 (Internal Server Error) add.html:6
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: upclick is not defined add.html:17
(anonymous function)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you define `upclick`? Post all of the scripts that you're including (or your HTML).

Comment: I'm working off of this: http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/ I figured that function fragment was enough?

Comment: mustn't it be "function upclick(.." instead of only "upclick(.." ??

Comment: Tried that and got the same error- fixed it though, it was a problem in my htaccess >.>